# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' Help needed with processing json data | Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable

My Problem:

[ Sourcecode of my Project: https://github.com/LarsE343/AdvancedBan-Webinterface ]

I have the following data:

```html
{
  "punishments": [
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520165103063", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "1520196276893", 
      "id": 4, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "TEMP_MUTE", 
      "reason": "none", 
      "start": "1520178276926", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 5, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180242009", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 6, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180567341", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 7, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "BAN", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180606379", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 8, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "Bitte \u00fcberdenke dein Verhalten", 
      "start": "1520181381607", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to put it in a table using :*ngFor="let punishments of _postsArray | async

but i am getting the error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0):

You should use ngFor over an array, change your HTML code as,

```
<table id="customers" *ngFor="let punishments of _postsArray.punishments | async">
```

Comment: Nope, Errors ive got: TypeError: _co._postsArray is undefined ; TypeError: _co._postsArray is undefined ;                     _co._postsArray is undefined;                               InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'                     thanks for adding errors with that great idea.  did you set up the project locally at your pc??

Comment: you already subscribed to `this.punishmentService.getPunishments()`, try this answer with out async pipe